# Pandas: a Loop across all Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stuck on this and I really appreciate any help,
I have this dataset

```
dataframe= pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [True, True,True,False,True,False], 
                              'col2': ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f']})
```

I want to change every `False` value from col1 with it's equivalent from col2 so i tried this

```
for x, y in zip(dataframe['col1'], dataframe['col2']):
    if x == False:
        dataframe['col1']=dataframe['col1'].replace(x, y,regex=True)
```

I expected this

```
   col1 col2
0  True    a
1  True    b
2  True    c
3     d    d
4  True    e
5     f    f
```

but instead, I got this

```
   col1 col2
0  True    a
1  True    b
2  True    c
3     d    d
4  True    e
5     d    f
```

Comment: To understand why your code is not working, you have to know that all values which are equal to `False` are changed if you enter the if condition for the first time. Afterwards none are left.

Comment: @mosc9575 Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need a loop and can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to replace the `False` by `nan` that are then filled with the second column.

```
dataframe['col1'] = dataframe['col1'].where(dataframe['col1'], dataframe['col2'])
print(dataframe)
   col1 col2
0  True    a
1  True    b
2  True    c
3     d    d
4  True    e
5     f    f
```

or the same result with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
dataframe['col1'] = dataframe['col1'].replace(False, dataframe['col2'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using boolean indexing and assigning 'col2' to 'col1':

```
df.loc[~df['col1'], 'col1'] = df['col2']
df
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2
0  True    a
1  True    b
2  True    c
3     d    d
4  True    e
5     f    f
```